Join claims that I'm attempting to merge object and int64 even though I'm not
I have two dataframes (on a server that I cannot take data out of, so unfortunately no reproducible example), both of which have a column called person2.
>>> group[['person2']].dtypes
person2    object
dtype: object

>>> df_returns[['person2']].dtypes
person2    object
dtype: object

>>> group[['person2']].join(df_returns[['person2']], on='person2')
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns for key 'person2'. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

However, group[['person2']].merge(df_returns[['person2']], on='person2') works. What causes this behavior?

Which pandas version did you use? Your error is unexpected, since join uses at least one of the indexes to perform the merge, there should be a different error message. Please craft a [mre] to try to reproduce the issue.

My guess is that you probably just want a merge, not a join.
